# Multiple include error

Tags: c++, include, ifndef

I am new to C++ and am trying to include two .h files I made.  The includes access each other so depending on the order I include them in one fails or the other. Because of this I know that the only possible problem has to be when I go to compile "$ g++ main.cpp foo1.cpp foo2.cpp" and it fails to read one. I used #IFnDef because I saw that that fixed the problem on another post, but it didn't change anything for me. Any ideas?

Comment: You often only need a forward declaration and including the entire file is then a waste of compiler effort.

Comment: Having two files include each other is not a good idea. Either combine the two files into one, or use forward declarations so that at least one of the files doesn't need to include the other. If you need help with forward declarations then you are going to have to post the code.

Comment: Check path for header files or both main.cpp and header needed resides in same folder ?. Between post your code of main file.

Answer (score 2):

As you've seen, you can't have two headers include each other.  Remember that an `#include` directive basically means "take the contents of that file and pretend it was pasted in right here".  If `header1.h` says to include the contents of `header2.h` at the beginning, but `header2.h` says to include the contents of `header1.h` at the beginning, and `header1.h` says (again) to include `header2.h` at the beginning…  you get the idea.

The `#define`/`#ifndef` trick (called an "[include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)") avoids infinite recursion by only allowing each header to be included once, but that means the compiler will see either the contents of `header1.h` followed by the contents of `header2.h`, or vice versa.  If the code in each header depends on things that are defined in the other, then either way you end up with code referring to things that aren't defined until later.

You may be able to avoid the circular dependency using what's called a "forward declaration" — *declaring* something that won't be fully *defined* until later.  For example:

```
// header1.h
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H

class Foo;  // Declaration only

class Bar {  // Definition
private:
  // You can have a pointer to a type that's only declared, not defined.
  Foo *p_foo;

  // ...
};

#endif  // ndef HEADER1_H

----

// header2.h

#ifndef HEADER2_H
#define HEADER2_H

#include "header1.h"

class Foo {  // Definition
private:
  // This requires class Bar to be defined, but that's OK, because it is.
  Bar bar;

  // ...
};

#endif  // ndef HEADER2_H
```

In this example `header1.h` doesn't have to include `header2.h`, because it doesn't need a *definition* of class `Foo`, only a declaration.  (In other words, the compiler only needs to know that a class called `Foo` *exists*; it doesn't need to know about its members yet.)